# 90s (or earlier) movie involving Nazis and the devil trapped in a mountain

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm searching for a movie I saw maybe 30-35 years ago. The story was the Nazis during the Second World War had either captured the devil or found him captured inside a mountain.

I don't remember it as a particularly good movie, it's not the reason I'm trying​ to find it. It just drives me crazy that I can't remember the name of the movie.

Comment: There is the first _Hellboy_ film, which starts with Nazis releasing Hellboy from a mountain, but that came out only 16 years ago.

Comment: @Mr Lister - Hellboy wasn't released from a mountain in the movie, he came into our world through some kind of interdimensional portal that Rasputin (with the help of the Nazis) had built. You might be thinking of the later scene where Rasputin was brought back into our reality by a blood sacrifice on some kind of magical maze-like structure hidden in some kind of arctic cave, maybe in a mountain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*The Keep* (1983)?

Set in WW2, in a Romanian town with some mountainy environments. Doesn't look really​ good either.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085780/):

> Nazis are forced to turn to a Jewish historian for help in battling the ancient demon they have inadvertently freed from its prison.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie nazis devil mountain site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: that was it! Your search fu is clearly way better than mine, I tried to find it on IMDB but failed. Watched it yesterday on Google Movie, it was actually better than I remembered. Thanks!

Comment: Never saw the movie, but I read the book many years ago, and its plot popped into my head as soon as I read the question title.

Comment: Never heard of it, but now I may have to watch it. If nothing else, it's got some good actors in it (Scott Glenn, Jurgen Prochnow, Morgan Sheppard, Ian McKellen, etc.)